# Как переключать сайт между дата-цетрами?

Tags: сервер, веб-служба, свич

Добрый день. Возможно заголовок не очень понятный, но я попытаюсь объяснить. Есть некоторые крупные проекты, которые умеют переключать пользователя на разные сервера. Обычно это выглядит так:

```
https://us1.testsite.com
https://us2.testsite.com
https://us3.testsite.com
```

Вот именно usX - это "псевдоним/префикс" того или иного сайта. Мне интерессно, как это компании организовали? Спасибо!

Comment: Скорее всего - редирект.

Comment: Что значит переключать?

Comment: Поищите про балансировку нагрузки

Answer (score 0):

Я так полагаю вопрос не зачем это нужно а как это реализуется. Как я уже сказал в коментарии к вопросу, называется это балансировка нагрузки. А реализуется это програмно или с испольованием специального оборудования (Load balancer). Если речь идет о датацентрах или больших компаниях то скорее всего они используют aппаратные балансировщики нагрузки. Те кто помельче -  програмные балансировщики, специализированные программные продукты или или обычные веб сервера. Большинство современных веб серверов поддерживют балансировку в той или иной степени. 
Принцип работы балансировщика прост. У него есть список доступых серверов (us1, us2, us3...) и он распределяет входящие запросы на эти сервера по определенному принципу (Метод балансировки). Существует множество методов, наиболее распростаненные:

- Round robbin - Веб сервер по умолчанию распределяет запросы равномерно между серверами. Может учитывать вес севрверов (мощнее/слабее).
- Распредлеление по количеству активых подключений. В этом методе запрос перенаправляеься на сервер с наименьшем количеством подключений, опять же с учетом веса
- Распределение по приоритету. В этом методе работает только сервер с большим приоритетом, остальные подключаются, как правило, только в случае его отказа
- По географическому признаку. Запрос перенапраляется  зависимости от того из какого сегмента сети приходит запрос. Например можно переключить на 'ближайший' сервер.
- Hash/IP. В этом методе клиент от которого прищел запрос привязывается к одному серверу, для этого в специальную таблицу помещается хеш-строка, указывающая на его IP. Как правило таким образом делается "sticky sessions" когда клиент всегда идет к одному серверу, а в случае его выхода подключение или невозможно или передается на другой серевер (часто с потерей состояния клиента).

Как обычно сложности возникают в деталях, так что не советую изобретать балансировщик самому.